# Converting a cis-alkene to trans-alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I was thinking about simple method to convert a *cis*-alkene alkene like *cis*-2-butene to *trans*-2-butene.

I came up with this method (the method can also be used to convert *trans* alkene to *cis* alkene):

- First use a peracid like *m*-CPBA to convert the *cis* alkene to an epoxide:
  [image]
- Then I used the Wittig reagent $\ce{PPh_3}$ to get a betaine. For the $\ce{- O-}$ to be able to attack $\ce{PPh3}$, they should be on same side. So rotation about $\ce{C-C}$ bond:

[image]

- Finally, the leaving of $\ce{POPh3}$:

[image]

I would like to know if my method is correct and if there are any other methods to bring about the conversion.

Comment: In cases of cis alkenes heating should suffice, the reverse way is actually quite interesting.

Comment: This method will convert trans to cis as well right?

Comment: Maybe. The theory is sound I think, not so sure about the praxis. We would have to dig into the literature.

Comment: I went through Jerry  March's book. This is from page 1374: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=by05kNKm_xYC&pg=PA1374&lpg=PA1374&dq=jerry+march+betaine&source=bl&ots=DsnZQB2oDQ&sig=nARlAk1_LUTtUCJKIFoSHexUAuU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW_bPtvuDJAhUNJI4KHdxqAWwQ6AEIGTAA#v=onepage&q=jerry%20march%20betaine&f=false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method looks fine. There is another simple method (with three steps though).

1. Convert the the *cis* alkene to a dibromo derivative using bromine;
2. Use two equivalents of $\ce{NaNH2}$ to get an alkyne (elimination);
3. Selective reduction to *trans* alkene by using sodium in liquid ammonia.
   However this requires that Hydrogen be present as a substituent on the double bond, on both carbons.

Comment: I know that method. Do you have anything else to add about my method?

Answer (score 4):

For *E*/*Z* trisubstituted alkenes capable of E<sub>2</sub> elimination the following sequence may apply. Add the elements of water in a ***syn***, *anti*-Markovnikov fashion to the double bond. Remove the elements of water as *p*-toluenesulfonic acid *via* ***anti*** E<sub>2</sub> elimination. The cycle below illustrates this point.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two other methods which I know, if you were to take a *cis*-1,2-diaryl alkene and expose it to UV light then you will excite the alkene into a 1,2-diradical. The $\ce{C-C}$ single bond in this is free to rotate.

It will then randomly form a $1:1$ mixture of the *cis* and *trans* isomers. As the photophysical properties of the two isomers are different (extinction coefficient) it is possible using light of a given wavelength to convert any mixture of *cis*/*trans* into a mixture with a given *cis*/*trans* ratio. A photostationary mixture. By changing the wavelength the ratio in the mixture changes.

Another method would be to react the *cis* alkene with a metal hydride which has a vacant coordination site such as $\ce{RuHCl(CO)(PPh3)2}$. Then do a β hydride elimination to form an alkene and the metal hydride again. This relates to the way in which *trans* fats are formed during the hydrogenation of plant oils (lipids with *cis* alkenes).